# zsh permission denied when accessing my home directory

Tags: zsh, access-denied

```
/Users/myname
zsh: permission denied: /Users/myname
```

I already gave the terminal full disc access and restarted my mac but it won't let me access this directory.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to enable `auto_cd`.  Add this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
setopt auto_cd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the command `/Users/myname`, it doesn't make sense, it's like asking a folder to execute.

You probably want to change directory, so `cd /Users/myname`

Answer (score 0):

Use following command and enter password when promoted (Administrator mode)

> sudo su

After this you can run script which is showing permission denied messages while accessing any directory or file